# How to get the latest inserted id for a model in backbonejs

Tags: backbone.js, codeigniter-restserver

I have a setup in which i add the models dynamically through a form. The data for the same is inserted in the row of a table. Once that row gets inserted I have a delete button attached to that row.

Now when i try to delete that inserted row, i am unable to because there is no unique id attached to that specific model and hence no id is sent in the DELETE request. But once i refresh the entire collection by doing a fetch, it works.

I tried this to fetch the whole model by using cid like this:

```
deleterow:function(){

window.rowList.get(this.model.cid).destroy({wait:true,success:function(){

 }});
```

This doesn't work. I am using phil sturgeon REST API for codeigniter.

EDIT:

```
$this->response(json_encode($Q),201);
```

Here $Q is populated like this:

```
    $this->db->where('id',$this->db->insert_id());
    $Q=$this->db->get('rows')->result();
```

In response i get data like this:

```
"[{\"id\":\"285\",\"name\":\"\",\"address\":\"\",\"city\":\"\",\"state\":\"\",\"zip\":\"\",\"email\":\"\",\"contact_number\":\"0\",\"alternate_number\":\"0\",\"row_type\":\"\",\"local_vat\":\"\",\"cst\":\"\",\"st\":\"\",\"excise_duty\":\"\"}]"
```

So its not in proper JSON format as well. What should i do?

Answer (score 3):

When Backbone creates or updates the model using `model.save` or `collection.create`, any JSON data sent back from the server is automatically `set` into the model. So for example, if you save a new model:

```
var model = collection.create({foo:'bar'});
```

This will cause a `POST` request to be sent to the model's url  root with the following body:

```
{"foo":"bar"}
```

You should configure your server to send back the created model as a response to the `POST` request, for example:

```
{"id":100, "foo":"bar"}
```

Backbone will then automatically copy any new and changed property from the response into the model, so you'll have:

```
var model = collection.create({foo:'bar'}, {success: function() {
  console.log(model.id); // -> 100
}});
```

Comment: no but i am using model.create method to add new models in a collection. What should be done in that case? See my edit as i have added what i have done on server side to respond back.

Comment: `Collection.create` works the same way as I described. It will copy the response properties to the new model. I edited my answer to reflect this. I don't know PHP or CodeIgniter, so can't help you with the server bit. However, depending on where you are looking at that response, it could be that it's actually valid. The backslashes are escape characters, and they could just be added by your IDE. If you are seeing the backslashes on the client side, then you indeed have a problem. Maybe someone else will come by and help you with that.